# How does Google analytics get demographic data (age/gender)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Where does google get this data from and is it possible to manually obtain this data on my own website without it (assuming it is in some kind of cookie/user-agent string/identifier/etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google gets its data from the 3rd Party double click cookie.

Here is a bit more detail from the [Google Analytics documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en#where)

If you are looking to get similar data - you can purchase it from services like Comscore but you would need to get something to identify your users against their database.

Why don't you want to use cookie/ user-agent?
My personal perspective is that even if users block cookies- then some data is better than no data.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logged in their google account, then google analytics collect demographic information like age, gender for that user. 
There are also other sources for collecting demographic data along with google account information like:

- Third-party double click cookie,
- Android advertising ID,
- IOS Identifier for advertisers.